# Python: How to remove whitespace from number in a string

Tags: python, string, join, merge, numbers

i want to remove whitespace from a string in PYTHON:

- example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
>   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
>   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris ***850 152*** nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
>   consequat. Duis aute irure ***360 458 000*** dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
>   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
>   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

- result wanted:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
>   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
>   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris ***850152*** nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
>   consequat. Duis aute irure ***360458000*** dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
>   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
>   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: Where is your implementation and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.sub` function like below,

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', r'', string)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qO5aO5/2)

**OR**

To replace inbetween one or more space characters.

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)', r'', string)
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 850 152 nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 360 458 000 dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', r'', s)
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 850152 nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 360458000 dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
```

**Regular Expression:**

```
(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  \d                       digits (0-9)
)                        end of look-behind
\s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                         more times)
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  \d                       digits (0-9)
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=\d)[ ]+(?=\d)
```

You can try the `re` module for this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/22

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=\d)[ ]+(?=\d)')
test_str = u"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 850 152 nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 360 458 000 dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
subst = u""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```